# How to separate cURL headers from body when multiple headers exist

Tags: php, curl

There are many questions on here asking how to separate the header of a cURL response from the body and the two methods I've seen are:

1. Use the length of the header and `substr()`
2. Use `explode("\r\n\r\n", $response, 2)`

However, the first method doesn't work when a proxy server is being used, and the second doesn't work when a 302 redirect is performed by the server and FOLLOW_LOCATION is set.

Therefore, my following code is insufficient, as the additional headers end up in `$body`:

```
$data      = explode("\r\n\r\n", $response, 2);
$header    = $data[0];
$body      = $data[1];
```

My current line of thought is to put the above code in a loop and after each iteration check if the first part of `$body` is `HTTP`, as the headers always look like:

```
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

If the first part of `$body` is `HTTP/`, then I would keep iterating, otherwise I would know that the headers had all been separated from the body. However, the downside I see to this is that if the body starts with `HTTP/` (which I suppose is unlikely), then that would cause a major issue.

Is there a better solution than the one I'm currently thinking of pursuing?

As a side note, I'm doing this because I need to retrieve both the response body and header(s).